# How can I know which pom belongs my current module in Intellij in a nested project with multiple POM.xml file?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a very big projects with modules and submodules, each module is a standard Java Maven project. So there are multiple POM files and in the Maven window of Intellij, I see multiple tasks. They are not organized by projects, but listed at the same level.

When I do changes, normally I only want to run Maven tasks(install, test) on the smallest scope, but I cannot find the "smallest" pom file related task in the window.

How can I do this without reopening this project in a separated Intellij instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I found it myself.

From the small wheel icon, you can find "Group by module". Click it.